# the name clientresponse does not exist in current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, httprequest, dotnetopenauth

[image]

I'm implementing OpenID in mvc3 razor code,(i use nerddinner openid example in razor) I use dotnetopenauth , I get this in authcontroller.
I use Assembly DotNetOpenAuth.dll, v2.0.50727

This is my web.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/>
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <!-- When targeting ASP.NET MVC 4, this assemblyBinding makes MVC 1 references relink
         to MVC 4 so libraries such as DotNetOpenAuth that compile against MVC 1 will work with it. -->
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

<pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="System.Globalization" />
        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to manually convert aspx to razor code, this made my code run clean

```
 var clientResponseInfo = (HttpRequestInfo)HttpRequestInfo.Create("GET", auth, headers: headers);
 response = RelyingParty.GetResponse(clientResponseInfo);
```